# How parse URL from JSON to clickable in android studio?

Tags: android, json, hyperlink

I am looking for help in android studio. I wanna parse from my json file hyperlink, which was clickable. Now when pressing showing just link with Toast help. I need, redirect to that url(to Playstore or Youtube), not show message with link.

**How it looks now -**

[image]

```js
package com.myapplication.good;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ItemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<DataAdapter> ListOfdataAdapter;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    String HTTP_JSON_URL = "https://link.com/file.php";

    String Image_Name_JSON = "image_title";

    String Image_URL_JSON = "image_url";

    String App_URL_JSON = "app_url";

    JsonArrayRequest RequestOfJSonArray ;

    RequestQueue requestQueue ;

    View view ;

    int RecyclerViewItemPosition ;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerOfrecyclerView;

    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    ArrayList<String> ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_items);

        ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick = new ArrayList<>();

        ListOfdataAdapter = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManagerOfrecyclerView = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOfrecyclerView);

        JSON_HTTP_CALL();

        // Implementing Click Listener on RecyclerView.
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ItemsActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    return true;
                }

            });
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                view = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                if(view != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                    //Getting RecyclerView Clicked Item value.
                    RecyclerViewItemPosition = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

                    // Showing RecyclerView Clicked Item value using Toast.
                    Toast.makeText(ItemsActivity.this, ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });


    }

    public void JSON_HTTP_CALL(){

        RequestOfJSonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_JSON_URL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        ParseJSonResponse(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ItemsActivity.this);

        requestQueue.add(RequestOfJSonArray);
    }

    public void ParseJSonResponse(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            DataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new DataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitle(json.getString(Image_Name_JSON));

                // Adding image title name in array to display on RecyclerView click event.
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.add(json.getString(App_URL_JSON));
                startActivity(intent);


                GetDataAdapter2.setImageUrl(json.getString(Image_URL_JSON));


            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ListOfdataAdapter.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ListOfdataAdapter, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebView` to display a web. Or use code below. More detail see [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.example.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for respond! So, how should looks this line - ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.add(json.getString(App_URL_JSON)); Thanks in advance

Comment: `ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition)` returns a string of url?

Comment: Yes, it's showing url from my mysql. I just wanna redirect to that url :) Two places here... //Getting RecyclerView Clicked Item value.
                    RecyclerViewItemPosition = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

 // Showing RecyclerView Clicked Item value using Toast.
                    Toast.makeText(ItemsActivity.this, ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Adding image title name in array to display on RecyclerView click event.
  ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.add(json.getString(App_URL_JSON));

Comment: Simply use this:String url = ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition);  Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: `uri` is decleared by`Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);` `uri` is red or `Uri` is red?

Comment: Did you improt `Uri`? If not, add code `import android.net.Uri;` to your java file

Comment: Are you still here? I have error on "intent missing method body" on last line - "startActivity(intent);" What i am missing thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, i was busy in recent days. However, congratulations on solving this problem. Please check my answer if convinient :).